# @AppStorage for favourite button for multiple views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, appstorage

I want to make it so you can favourite a "landmark" in one view (LandmarkDetail), and access a list of all the "landmarks" in another view with the ones I've favourited highlighted using ***@AppStorage***. So far I have the favourite button working in the LandmarkDetail view with @AppStorage, but not in the view with the list.

**Here is my code for the favourite button**

```
struct FavoriteButton: View {
    @AppStorage ("isFavorite") var isFavorite: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            isFavorite.toggle()
        } label: {
            Label("Toggle Favorite", systemImage: isFavorite ? "star.fill" : "star")
                .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                .foregroundColor(isFavorite ? .yellow : .gray)
        }
    }
}
```

**Code from the landmark detail view**

```
struct LandmarkDetail: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Text(landmark.name)
                        .font(.title)
                    FavoriteButton()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code for the rows in the list view**

This is the one not working yet, so far it just pulls the data from a JSON.

```
struct LandmarkRow: View {
    var landmark: Landmark
    @AppStorage ("isFavorite") var isFavorite: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            landmark.image
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .cornerRadius(8)
            Text(landmark.name)
            
            Spacer()
            
            if landmark.isFavorite {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to come up with a more appropriate store for your favourites. You only have a single `isFavorite` value, but presumably you have multiple landmarks.

Comment: AppStorage isn't the right solution. It is more suitable for things like user preferences.  Core data is more appropriate

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11. Found this: 
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-combine-core-data-and-swiftui

It looks promising and I'll continue from this.