# Core data for favourite buttons

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I want to make it so you can favourite a "landmark" in one view (LandmarkDetail), and access a list of all the "landmarks" in another view with the ones I've favourited highlighted. First I used "@AppStorrage" but I was told too to use Core Data for it instead. So far I have the favourite button working in the LandmarkDetail view with "@AppStorage" but apparently I need to change that so it uses Core Data.

I've look around to get an understanding of how to do it with Core Data but I could really use a helping hand if anyone can help. I've already seen and read some tutorials about core data and how to set it up, but I can't find anything for my specific problem where I pull in data from a JSON and I need Core Data to handle the favourite feature.

**Here is my code for the favourite button**

```
struct FavoriteButton: View {
    @AppStorage ("isFavorite") var isFavorite: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            isFavorite.toggle()
        } label: {
            Label("Toggle Favorite", systemImage: isFavorite ? "star.fill" : "star")
                .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                .foregroundColor(isFavorite ? .yellow : .gray)
        }
    }
}
```

**Code from the landmark detail view**

```
struct LandmarkDetail: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Text(landmark.name)
                        .font(.title)
                    FavoriteButton()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code for the rows in the list view**

This is the one not working yet, so far it just pulls the data from a JSON.

**MODEL**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct Landmark: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var park: String
    var state: String
    var description: String
    var isFavorite: Bool
    var isFeatured: Bool
    
    var category: Category
    enum Category: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
        case lakes = "Lakes"
        case rivers = "Rivers"
        case mountains = "Mountains"
    }
    
    private var imageName: String
    var image: Image{
        Image(imageName)
    }
    var featureImage: Image? {
        isFeatured ? Image(imageName + "_feature") : nil
    }
    
    private var coordinates: Coordinates
    var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: coordinates.latitude,
            longitude: coordinates.longitude)
    }
    
    struct Coordinates: Hashable, Codable {
        var latitude: Double
        var longitude: Double
    }
    
}
```

```
import Foundation
import Combine

final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var landmarks: [Landmark] = load("landmarkData.json")
    var hikes: [Hike] = load("hikeData.json")
    @Published var profile = Profile.default
    
    var features: [Landmark] {
        landmarks.filter { $0.isFeatured }
    }
    
    var categories: [String: [Landmark]] {
        Dictionary(
            grouping: landmarks,
            by: { $0.category.rawValue }
        )
    }
}

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {

    let data: Data


    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)

    else {

        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")

    }


    do {

        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)

    } catch {

        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")

    }


    do {

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)

    } catch {

        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")

    }

}
```

Comment: `isFavorite` is not specific to the landmark, it's shared for the entire app since it's using `AppStorage`. Have you created a `xcdatamodeld` file & set your model? If not, do that first.

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73248628/appstorage-for-favourite-button-for-multiple-views)? You need to understand what your data model is and how to map your data, many landmarks means many isFavorite flags.

Comment: This would be a large undertaking. Start a new CoreData project with CoreData built in. Create a Landmark entity and then start adapting. It will take a while you are switching from a struct/value Landmark to a CoreData/ObservableObject/reference Landmark. It is major work. You won’t get an answer for this on SO.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson what I don't get is how I need to start using core data in my project. All I can find is how to use it to create new entries like "moviename + director" and save that. What I have now is a JSON where I pull in some existing data, and need to be able to favourite. I've added my data model to the post now.

Comment: Ok I saw that part about core data now but your question is then way to broad. Since your json is in a file rather than being downloaded I suppose one approach is to load the json into core data at startup or to create a SQLite file initialized with the data that you use. Both cases have been asked about earlier.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a .xcdatamodeld file named Landmarks. You can create it by pressing right button on the principal folder of your project and searching `Data Model`. After you need to create a new `Entity` named `Landmark`. You can add attributes showed in your model like `id, name, park, etc...` with their types. After you need to create a new Swift file in which you can create you Core Data Controller like this:

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {

   let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Landmarks")

    init() {
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Core Data failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Successively, you need to add to your `LandmarksApp.swift` file the following code:

```
struct LandmarksApp: App {
@StateObject private var dataController = DataController()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Continue adding this to your `LandmarkDetail` view:

```
struct LandmarkDetail: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Text(landmark.name)
                        .font(.title)
                    FavoriteButton()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To create a new item and add to Core Data you can write:

```
let landmark = Landmark(context: moc)
landmark.id = id
landmark.name = name
landmark.park = park
etc...
try? moc.save()
```

For your JSON data you can create a function that convert all JSON data in Core Data following these steps.